# django-rest-framework: Setting up serializer for foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my model, I have two tables named: `Vtable` and `Vdata`. Each virtual table (in `Vtable`) has entries of virtual data stored in `Vdata`.

I'm trying to make a view that would show the list of `Vdata` corresponding to each `Vtable`

My serializer isn't working and I think it's because I'm doing it backwards.
I think the problem is in this line:
`table_id = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)`

For reference, I get this error: `'Vtable' object is not iterable`

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Vtable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField('date added')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.table_name

class Vdata(models.Model):
    table_id = models.ForeignKey(Vtable)
    table_pk = models.IntegerField()
    column_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    column_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField('date added')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.added_date)
```

Here is my serializers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from vtables.models import Vtable, Vdata

class TableSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.Field(source='user.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Vtable
        fields = ('table_name', 'added_date', 'user')

class EntrySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    table_id = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vdata
        fields = ('table_id', 'table_pk', 'column_1', 'column_2', 'added_date')
```

Here is the view that calls it:

```
class EntryList(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        entries = Vdata.objects.all()
        serializer = EntrySerializer(entries, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data

        class Meta:
            model = Vdata
            fields = ('table_id', 'table_pk', 'column_1', 'column_2', 'added_date')
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of how you might do this:

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.Field(source='user.username')
    entries = EntrySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vtable
        fields = ('table_name', 'added_date', 'user', 'entries')

class EntrySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Vdata
        fields = ('table_id', 'table_pk', 'column_1', 'column_2', 'added_date')
```

And for the view:

```
class EntryList(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Vtable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TableSerializer
```

Do not forget about:

setting `related_name='entries'` in your model foreign key field definition.

Comment: I get `'Vtable' object has no attribute 'entries'` when I do that

Comment: Yes, I forgot: you should have related_name='entries' when you declare the ForeingKey to Table on your Entry model. So: table_id = models.ForeignKey(Vtable, related_name='entries')

Comment: [{"event":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"event":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"event":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},]}]

Comment: @AdelaN I followed your sample and all values are fetched but returns as empty sets. Like above, what is my mistake

Comment: @Antro I can't tell just by the output. Perhaps you missed something or perhaps you are using a different version of DRF where this snippet no longer works as intended. Bear in mind that this answer is from 2014, so it is possible that the internal functionalities of DRF have changed quite a bit.

Comment: @AdelaN Thanks for your response. I'll look over the issue